# Is it possible to add other users to different slack channels using Slack API as admin?

Tags: slack-api, slack

The **channel.join** api in the slack web api does not have a slack userid field. The problem is since there are lot of channels in our slack team user gets confused on which channels to join. So we have segregated channels based on internal teams. And if an user selects his team he should be able to auto-join all the channels which are related to him.

As an admin of the slack team is it possible to add other users to different slack channels using Slack API?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to raise your question

Comment: I have raised my question in the title itself. Is it possible to add other users to different slack channels using slack api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Slack API method `channel.invite` to invite users to any slack public slack channel. It allows you to specify the channel and user by ID.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite) for the documentation.

Comment: `channel.invite` method is deprecated. You should be using [`conversations.invite`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite) now.